# TestFlight rejection with no explanation

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

Two weeks ago I submitted watchOS app to TestFlight. It was rejected the same day with no explanation. I clicked the contact link and submitted a request to learn why my app was rejected. No response. I submitted another request for an explanation a couple of days ago. No response. I don't mind my app being rejected. I just want to know why so I can fix it. What are my options here?

Comment: TestFlight review is pretty lenient. It may be crashing on launch. Have you installed flight build yourself to see what it does? Did you check for emails from apple?

Comment: I have installed the app and it runs great in both the Simulator and on my Apple Watch. I checked everywhere for emails from Apple about this and didn't find any. What's even more frustrating is that I'm not getting responses to my followup messages to Apple.

Comment: Ok, but have you tested the TestFlight build that you have asked Apple to approve?  You don't need Apple to approve a TestFlight build for you to install it yourself, only for people who aren't part of your developer program.  So, start by installing your app from TestFlight and seeing what happens.

Comment: @MarkVolkmann how did you solve?

Comment: I think I just tried again a few days later and it worked. My watchOS app has now made it into the App Store.